# List<String> to ArrayList<String> conversion issue

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I have a following method...which actually takes the list of sentences and splits each sentence into words. Here is it:

```
public List<String> getWords(List<String> strSentences){
allWords = new ArrayList<String>();
    Iterator<String> itrTemp = strSentences.iterator();
    while(itrTemp.hasNext()){
        String strTemp = itrTemp.next();
        allWords = Arrays.asList(strTemp.toLowerCase().split("\\s+"));          
    }
    return allWords;
}
```

I have to pass this list into a hashmap in the following format

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>
```

so this method returns List and I need an ArrayList? If I try to cast it doesn't work out... any suggestions?

Also, if I change the ArrayList to List in a HashMap, I get

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

because of this line in my code

```
sentenceList.add(((Element)sentenceNodeList.item(sentenceIndex)).getTextContent());
```

Any better suggestions?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

First of all, why is the map a `HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>` and not a `HashMap<String, List<String>>`? Is there some reason why the value must be a specific implementation of interface `List` (`ArrayList` in this case)?

`Arrays.asList` does not return a `java.util.ArrayList`, so you can't assign the return value of `Arrays.asList` to a variable of type `ArrayList`.

Instead of:

```
allWords = Arrays.asList(strTemp.toLowerCase().split("\\s+"));
```

Try this:

```
allWords.addAll(Arrays.asList(strTemp.toLowerCase().split("\\s+")));
```

Comment: And specifically the `UnsupportedOperationException` is caused because the `Arrays.asList` method returns a fixed-sized list backed by an array - it cannot be modified. The solution presented here by @Jesper will avoid that.

Answer (score 212):

Cast works where the actual instance of the list is an `ArrayList`. If it is, say, a `Vector` (which is another extension of `List`) it will throw a ClassCastException.

The error when changing the definition of your HashMap is due to the elements later being processed, and that process expects a method that is defined only in `ArrayList`. The exception tells you that it did not found the method it was looking for.

Create a new `ArrayList` with the contents of the old one.

```
new ArrayList<String>(myList);
```

Answer (score 46):

Take a look at [ArrayList#addAll(Collection)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll(java.util.Collection))

> Appends all of the elements in the specified collection to the end of
>   this list, in the order that they are returned by the specified
>   collection's Iterator. The behaviour of this operation is undefined if
>   the specified collection is modified while the operation is in
>   progress. (This implies that the behaviour of this call is undefined if
>   the specified collection is this list, and this list is nonempty.)

So basically you could use

```
ArrayList<String> listOfStrings = new ArrayList<>(list.size());
listOfStrings.addAll(list);
```

Answer (score 20):

In Kotlin List can be converted into ArrayList through passing it as a constructor parameter.

```
ArrayList(list)
```

Answer (score 5):

[`Arrays.asList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) does not return instance of [`java.util.ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)but it returns instance of `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList`.

You will need to convert to ArrayList if you want to access `ArrayList` specific information

```
allWords.addAll(Arrays.asList(strTemp.toLowerCase().split("\\s+")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried and tested approach.

```
public static ArrayList<String> listToArrayList(List<Object> myList) {
        ArrayList<String> arl = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Object object : myList) {
            arl.add((String) object);
        }
        return arl;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This comes a bit late but thought of putting in a simple way for the answer of **converting List to ArrayList**.

**Simple way**

```
public static <T> ArrayList<T> listToArrayList(List<T> list) {
    return list != null ? new ArrayList<>(list) : null;
}
```

**Classic way**

```
public static  <T> ArrayList<T>  listToArrayList(List<T> list) {
    ArrayList<T> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    if (list != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            arrayList.add(list.get(i));
            i++;
        }
        // or simply
        // arrayList.addAll(list);
    }
    return  arrayList;
}
```

**Usage**

```
listToArrayList(yourList);
```

Answer (score 0):

> ArrayList listOfStrings = new ArrayList<>(list.length);
> listOfStrings.addAll(Arrays.asList(list));

In case of object list you can use this way to convert Model[] list to ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

With the advent of the Java streaming API (March, 2014), the following might now be considered the preferred approach:

```
    public List<String> getWordsFunctionally(List<String> sentences) { 
        List<String> list = sentences.stream()
            .map(s -> List.of(s.toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\p{Punct}", "").split("\\s+")))
            .flatMap(List::stream)
//          .distinct() // if you don't want duplicates
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        
        return list;
    }
```

Note that the original code had a bug in it: with each iteration, the values in `allWords` are replaced with the current array derived from splitting the sentence into words.

```
allWords = Arrays.asList(strTemp.toLowerCase().split("\\s+"));
```

This should read

```
allWords.addAll(Arrays.asList(strTemp.toLowerCase().split("\\s+")));
```

Also, it doesn't remove punctuation.