# Hadoop - ClassCastException: LongWritable cannot be cast to Long

Tags: java, hadoop

I got the following `ClassCastException` but not sure what is wrong with the code:

```
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:492)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:552)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
    at uk.ac.man.cs.comp38211.exercise.PositionalTFTerm.<init>(BasicInvertedIndex.java:264)
    at uk.ac.man.cs.comp38211.exercise.PositionalTFTerm.of(BasicInvertedIndex.java:301)
    at uk.ac.man.cs.comp38211.exercise.PositionalTFTerm.merge(BasicInvertedIndex.java:276)
    at java.util.stream.Collectors$1OptionalBox.accept(Collectors.java:706)
    at java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$groupingBy$45(Collectors.java:909)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$3ReducingSink.accept(ReduceOps.java:169)
    at com.google.common.collect.Streams$2.tryAdvance(Streams.java:366)
    at java.util.Spliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterator.java:326)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
    at uk.ac.man.cs.comp38211.exercise.BasicInvertedIndex$MyMapper.map(BasicInvertedIndex.java:103)
```

Here is the line that throws the exception, in the constructor, I am trying to convert the `List<Long> positions` to `ArrayListWritable<LongWritable> positions`:

[image: im]

Below is the implementation of `ArrayListWritable`:

```java
/*
 * Cloud9: A MapReduce Library for Hadoop Licensed under the Apache License,
 * Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
 * with the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 Unless required by applicable law
 * or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the License is
 * distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
 * KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific language
 * governing permissions and limitations under the License.
 */

package uk.ac.man.cs.comp38211.io.array;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable;

import java.io.DataInput;
import java.io.DataOutput;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * <p>
 * Writable extension of a Java ArrayList. Elements in the list must be
 * homogeneous and must implement Hadoop's Writable interface.
 * </p>
 * 
 * @param <E>
 *            type of list element
 * 
 * @author Jimmy Lin
 * @author Tamer Elsayed
 */

public class ArrayListWritable<E extends Writable> extends ArrayList<E> implements Writable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4911321393319821791L;

    /**
     * Creates an ArrayListWritable object.
     */
    public ArrayListWritable()
    {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * Creates an ArrayListWritable object from an ArrayList.
     */
    public ArrayListWritable(ArrayList<E> array)
    {
        super(array);
    }

    /**
     * Deserializes the array.
     * 
     * @param in
     *            source for raw byte representation
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException
    {
        this.clear();

        int numFields = in.readInt();
        if (numFields == 0) return;
        String className = in.readUTF();
        E obj;
        try
        {
            Class<E> c = (Class<E>) Class.forName(className);
            for (int i = 0; i < numFields; i++)
            {
                obj = (E) c.newInstance();
                obj.readFields(in);
                this.add(obj);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Serializes this array.
     * 
     * @param out
     *            where to write the raw byte representation
     */
    public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException
    {
        out.writeInt(this.size());
        if (size() == 0) return;
        E obj = get(0);

        out.writeUTF(obj.getClass().getCanonicalName());

        for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++)
        {
            obj = get(i);
            if (obj == null)
            {
                throw new IOException("Cannot serialize null fields!");
            }
            obj.write(out);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Generates human-readable String representation of this ArrayList.
     * 
     * @return human-readable String representation of this ArrayList
     */
    public String toString()
    {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        sb.append("[");
        for (int i = 0; i < this.size(); i++)
        {
            if (i != 0) sb.append(", ");
            sb.append(this.get(i));
        }
        sb.append("]");

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

May I know how can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: You are adding a `LongWritable` dynamic object to a strictly `Long` list? But you initialize this `Long` list as an `ArrayListWritable` dynamic list before that? Or am I missing something? What datatype should this `positions` list contain?

Comment: Sorry the naming is confusing, the `positions` is a constructor argument with type `List<Long>`, The `this.positions` is an instance variable with type `ArrayListWritable<LongWritable>`, I have expanded the picture in the question to make it more clear

Comment: @Coursal In the constructor, I am trying to convert the `List<Long>` to `ArrayListWritable<LongWritable>`

Comment: Have you tried to add a method on your `ArrayListWritable` class to make this conversion (something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/58735931/5644037)? I don't believe it's a common variable naming issue of course, it's interesting to me that you are trying to do the conversion like that on the fly.

Comment: @Coursal Thanks for the suggestion, but I just tried it but it is still the same error, the only difference is that the error is now in the method in the `ArrayListWritable`

Comment: @Coursal It works without problem if I store it directly as `List<Long>` then only make the conversion in the `write` and `readFields` method in `PositionalTFTerm` class, I guess that is the best for now.